# How to preload style image to use it when server is down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a javascript widget which indicates the server status with alarm LED picture. The picture is selected by applying appropriate class to DOM element with appropriate style in CSS defined.

The problem is that when server is down, it is unable to provide image file for the style. So, my button just appears empty.

The question is: how to preload the image to browser cache so it can and would display it when server is down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can preload the image by creating an `img` element and assigning the path to the `src`:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "/path/to/image";
```

That'll put it in cache. I don't think you even have to put it in the DOM for the browser to load it, but if you want to be absolutely sure, you can do this:

```
img.style.position = "absolute";
img.style.left = "-10000px";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

That loads it, but off-page where the user won't see it. It might even be best to do that with whatever element you're actually displaying the image on, and then just move the element to where you need it to be when displaying it, to avoid having the browser send a new `GET` with an `If-Modified-Since` when you're showing it, but in theory if your cache headers are correct the browser shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 2):

There are all sorts of advanced methods you could use to pre-cache the image, but I would recommend going the simpler route.

I'd do one of the following:

1. Use simple styles to create the alert effect (huge border, bright red, etc.)
2. Upload the image to a (reliable) third-party service. There are several.

That way, you're not dependent on your code or server working correctly for the alert to work, when presumably, that's what you're trying to monitor with this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can define background from data:image.
Check:
[here](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/) or [here](http://www.scalora.org/projects/uriencoder/).